# Creating an Array of Likes from Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objects

These are parts of my entire code. So what I am trying to do is create separate arrays of the values I like or dislike and output them in my html File onclick. I tried to create an empty array and push value but my final array ends up empty.

**Script.js**

```
const showRandomMovie = async() => {
  const movieInfo = document.getElementById('movieInfo');
  if (movieInfo.childNodes.length > 0) {
    clearCurrentMovie();
  };
  const movies = await getMovies();
  const randomMovie = getRandomMovie(movies);
  const info = await getMovieInfo(randomMovie);
  displayMovie(info);

};
playBtn.onclick = showRandomMovie;
```

**helper.js**

```
const displayMovie = (movieInfo) => {
    const moviePosterDiv = document.getElementById('moviePoster');
    const movieTextDiv = document.getElementById('movieText');
    const likeBtn = document.getElementById('likeBtn');
    const dislikeBtn = document.getElementById('dislikeBtn');
  
    // Create HTML content containing movie info
    const moviePoster = createMoviePoster(movieInfo.poster_path);
    const titleHeader = createMovieTitle(movieInfo.title);
    const overviewText = createMovieOverview(movieInfo.overview);
    const releaseHeader = createReleaseDate(movieInfo.release_date)
    // Append title, poster, and overview to page
    moviePosterDiv.appendChild(moviePoster);
    movieTextDiv.appendChild(titleHeader);
    movieTextDiv.appendChild(overviewText);
    movieTextDiv.appendChild(releaseHeader)

    showBtns();
    likeBtn.onclick = likeMovie;
    dislikeBtn.onclick = dislikeMovie;
};

const likeMovie = () => {
    
    clearCurrentMovie();
    showRandomMovie();
};

// After disliking a movie, clears the current movie from the screen and gets another random movie
const dislikeMovie = () => {
    clearCurrentMovie();
    showRandomMovie();
};
```

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what `getMovies` returns (presumably JSON), how you're parsing that JSON into data, or what `getRandomMovie` or `getMovieInfo` do.

Comment: you've literally posted "all your code" but nothing useful to solve your question.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Getmovies returns Json using api keys and endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create arrays for the likes and dislikes and push it to an array. Pass it along to your methods.

```js
likeBtn.onclick = () => rateMovie('likes', movieInfo);
dislikeBtn.onclick = () => rateMovie('dislikes', movieInfo);
```

have the method add it to the array

```js
const ratings = {
  likes: [],
  dislikes: [],
};

const rateMovie = (type, data) => {
    ratings[type].push(data);
    clearCurrentMovie();
    showRandomMovie();
};
```